# Error: 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration with seperated packages. Spring boot

Tags: spring, package, entitymanagerfactory

I am writing a spring boot project. I am separating my project to packages (controller, model, repository and services).
but when i run my project, i have this error.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

configuration:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Were you able to get `entityManagerFactory` before separation, could you share the hibernate configuration properties?

Comment: check the update please

Comment: not pom.xml, the hibernate configuration which you used in application.properties or application.yml

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect.     spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true

Comment: The problem was solved. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you made it work, make sure you have below annotations enabled `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.abc.dao.repositories")`
`@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.model" })`
`@ComponentScan(basePackages={ "com.abc.controller", "com.abc.service", "com.abc.dao" })`

Comment: Yes that was the problem. Thank You.